# Get raw POST payload in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, post, flask

I am sending text by cUrl

```
curl -X POST -d "Separate account charge and opdeducted fr" http://192.168.50.8/text
```

and try to get

```
@application.route("/text",methods=['POST'])
def clausIE():
      content = request.data
      text = str(content, encoding="utf-8")
```

But get empty string, what I am doing wrong?

Note: I use Python3.6

Comment: Umm, you need to return something in clauseIE.

Comment: using `request.get_data()` instead of `request.data` should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a Flask problem, you are using the wrong `curl` options.

The `-d` switch should only be used for form data. `curl` automatically will set the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which means that Flask will load the raw body content and parse it as a form. You'll have to set a different Content-Type header manually, using `-H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'` or another mime-type more appropriate to your data.

You also want to use `--data-binary`, not `-d` (`--data`), as the latter also tries to parse the content into key-value fields and will remove newlines:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
   --data-binary "Separate account charge and opdeducted fr" \
   http://192.168.50.8/text
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer seems to be scattered around some comments and the accepted reply. So to summarize this, the Python Flask code should look like

```
@application.route("/text",methods=['POST'])
def clausIE():
    content = request.get_data()

    text = str(content, encoding="utf-8") 

    return text
```

and this is what you should have at your terminal

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "Hello World!" http://192.168.50.8/text
```

At my own setup (OS X) I am allowed to drop `-X POST` and to wrap the URL around quotes, so that gives

```
curl --data-binary "Hello World!" "http://192.168.50.8/text"
```